# Find $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (\frac{2^{1/n}}{n+1} +\frac{2^{2/n}}{n+1/2}+\dots+\frac{2^{n/n}}{n+{1/n}})$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Find the  following  limit
>    $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (\frac{2^{1/n}}{n+1} +\frac{2^{2/n}}{n+1/2}+\dots+\frac{2^{n/n}}{n+{1/n}})$$

**My attempts**  : $$\frac{2^{1/n}}{n+1} +\frac{2^{2/n}}{n+1/2}+....+\frac{2^{n/n}}{n+{1/n}}= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{2^{k/n}}{n+1/k} =\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{2^{k/n}}{1+1/kn}.$$
After that I was  thinking  about Riemann sum, but  $2^{k/n}$  creates   confusion in my mind. So  I'm not able  to proceed  further.

Any hints/solution  will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Note that
$$\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}}\cdot\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} 2^{k/n}\leq \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{2^{k/n}}{n+\frac{1}{k}}\leq  \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} 2^{k/n}.$$
Then use the fact that $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} 2^{k/n}$ is a Riemann sum of $\int_0^1 2^x\,dx$.

Comment: Give  me  5 minutes   let  me  thinks  about ur  answer

Comment: thanks  U @Robert

Answer (score 1):

It is a Riemann sum as you say: $\int_0^1 2^x \, dx = 1/\ln 2$. The denominator vanishes as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: I don't think the given sum is  Riemann sum of the function you're using. As shown in the other answer, it though can be sandwiched between two expressions using that Riemann sum...

Comment: Agreed, it isn't, but the difference is zero in the limit as you say. I think we were typing away at the same time ...